# React Native Expo Splash screen, async render

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, expo

How to render react native component in the background?  I want a splash screen, but the current example only allows async downloading data.

I have tried SplashScreen of AppLoading in Expo, but it only allows to download data first, it doesn't allow for async render for components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Asset, SplashScreen } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.preventAutoHide();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Image
            source={require('./assets/images/splash.gif')}
            onLoad={this._cacheResourcesAsync}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      // ...
    );    
  }

  _cacheResourcesAsync = async () => {
    SplashScreen.hide();

   // ....

    await Promise.all(cacheImages);
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
}
```

This only download data asynchronously, but I want to render asynchronously.